# Function that takes maximum real value of a vector?

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

Given a complex vector $\vec{v}$, I'm looking for a mathematical function that takes the maximum of the *real* components of that vector. Here's a quick example:

$$
\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
-2 \\
-1 \\
5i \\
6i
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm looking for a function, call it realmax($\vec{v}$), that behaves like so:

$$
\text{realmax}(\vec{v}) = -1
$$

So even though the *magnitudes* of the $5i$ and $6i$ components are larger than 1, the function will return -1, the largest real value, by construction.

I know I can't simply take $\text{Re}(\vec{v})$, because that would produce

$$
\text{Re}(\vec{v}) = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
-2 \\
-1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix} \xrightarrow{\quad\quad\quad} \text{max}(\text{Re}(\vec{v})) = 0
$$

which is not the target behavior. The vector $\vec{v}$ can have positive values in general, it just doesn't in this specific example.

Does this kind of function exist?

Comment: How is the maximum real value defined for another quick example: 

$$
\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
-3 \\
-2 \\
-1 \\
1+5i \\
2+6i
\end{bmatrix}\quad ?
$$

Comment: @KurtG. Good point. In that case, it would return realmax(v) = -1 once again. My goal is for the function to only look at the real elements, while ignoring complex / imaginary ones.

Comment: What does it do if you plug in a vector with imaginary parts in all components?

Comment: @jleff . When Timmathy's question is answered we have a complete definition of the "function" .  In that sense the function exists. Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Yes, this is perfect, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a assignment of elements of a domain to one element in a codomain $B$.

So to verify this is a function we have to define a domain and a codomain. In your case is the domain $\mathbb{C}^n$ and the codomain $\mathbb{R}$. So now we have to look that it assigns each element to ONE element. Here it gets tricky with your definition. What if i plug $0+3i$ in that function? Will it behave diffrently when i plug in $3i$? If it will it can't be a function.

If you want it to be a real function you need define a few rules and a explicit definition/case distinction for your boarder cases which you want to differ from $\max(\text{Re}(v))$.